# Remote control PDF presentation on Mac using Apple Watch

Tags: preview, apple-watch, remote-control

It is possible to [use an Apple Watch to control a Keynote presentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/use-a-remote-tan85f5c958c/mac) (switch slides, etc.)

However, I prepare my presentations using LaTeX and Beamer, which generate PDFs. I use Preview.app on my Mac to present.

Is there some built-in functionality or an app (preferably free) which allows me to use the Apple Watch to switch slides on my PDF presentations? I am open to switching to a different PDF viewer if necessary.

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I would also love to do this.